# icp registeration pcl library

Tags: registration, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I'm trying to align two point clouds together, as you can see in the image below .. the white cloud is my source cloud and the black one is my target ... for some reason the alignment is shifted by a certain value as you can see (red point cloud).
Any suggestions on how I can make this a perfect fit ? I tried changing some parameters (check the code below) but with no difference at all.
[image]

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr sourceCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr targetCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
    pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::Ptr finalCloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>);
  Eigen::Matrix4f icp_Transformation;

  //Assign both point clouds as source and target
  pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ>("plate_pcd.pcd", *sourceCloud);
  pcl::copyPointCloud(*holes_pos_intertial, *targetCloud);
  
  // ICP object.
    pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> registration;
    registration.setInputSource(sourceCloud);
    registration.setInputTarget(targetCloud);
  registration.setTransformationEpsilon(0.0000000000000000000001);
  registration.setEuclideanFitnessEpsilon(0.0000000000000000000001);
  // double RMS = EMVS::PCGeometry::computeCloudRMS(targetCloud, sourceCloud, 1.0);
  // std::cout << "RMS is :" << RMS <<  std::endl;
    registration.align(*finalCloud);
    if (registration.hasConverged())
    {
        std::cout << "ICP converged." << std::endl
                  << "The score is " << registration.getFitnessScore() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Transformation matrix:" << std::endl;
        std::cout << registration.getFinalTransformation() << std::endl;
    icp_Transformation = registration.getFinalTransformation();

    }
    else std::cout << "ICP did not converge." << std::endl;

}
```

Comment: If anyone knows a better place to discuss this issue please provide it to me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve a perfect alignment with a too small dataset. But if you still want to try you can change your loss function. Different ICP types generally try to minimize different variants. In your case point-to-point ICP should have a better result since point clouds are compatible.

Also you can play with the parameters of the icp.

```
registration.setMaximumIterations (500);
registration.setTransformationEpsilon (1e-9);
registration.setMaxCorrespondenceDistance (0.05);
registration.setEuclideanFitnessEpsilon (1);
registration.setRANSACOutlierRejectionThreshold (1.5);
```

These and [other](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_iterative_closest_point.html) parameters depend on your data and unless you change them you wouldn't get much, i.e parameters I have given may not work well for your case but I guess you can get a better alignment.